# Parse particular datatime format Python

Tags: python, regex, datetime

[PYTHON]
having  a column in my dataframe where date has following format:
'JAN07' or '200701' 
Is there a simple way to transform this type of date to : 
'01-2007' for example?
Maybe using regular expression?

Answer (score 0):

First convert your string column to proper datetimes:

```
df['colname'] = pd.to_datetime(df['colname'], format='%Y%m') # e.g. 200701
```

Then back to string in the format you want:

```
df['colname'] = df['colname'].dt.strftime('%m-%Y')
```

This two-step process ensures you have no invalid values, yet is relatively fast because it is vectorized (no Python loops).

Comment: thankyou,but this one works for the second case. What about this "JAN07" ?

Comment: @ok_dataentry: JAN can be parsed with `%b` (abbreviated month) as detailed here: http://strftime.org/ - so `'%b%y'` will parse `"JAN07"`.

Answer (score 0):

This might help.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ['JAN07', '200701']})
print df["A"].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y%m').strftime('%m-%Y') if x[0].isdigit() else datetime.strptime(x, '%b%y').strftime('%m-%Y'))
```

**Output:**

```
0    01-2007
1    01-2007
Name: A, dtype: object
```

Comment: This solution will be quite slow (because it uses apply+lambda).  If both formats exist in the same column, there are still vectorized solutions which will be efficient.